# Is there a limit for the size of a single file in TFVC source control for TFS 2015?

Tags: tfs-2015, tfvc

One of our developers tried to upload a 20mb SSIS package into TFVC from the Webportal He got the following error: Failed to checkin changes: The maximum request size of 26214400 bytes was exceeded.

What setting do I change to allow that file to be uploaded to TFVC?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a limit for the size of a single file when you upload/checkin **from web access**. The maximum total size allowed to be uploaded is **20 MB**. However this limitation does not apply to using your favorite `IDE` or `tf.exe` for this operation.

We could not increase the size limitation now, you could use visual studio with Team Explorer or `tf.exe` (See [Checkin command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/checkin-command?view=vsts)) to check in large files.

Reference the same issue in this thread : [[TFS 2017] how to increase maximum total size of files when checking files from web browser?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8e508621-f1bd-4c3b-a4b1-b2cb255ee14f/tfs-2017-how-to-increase-maximum-total-size-of-files-when-checking-files-from-web-browser)